# I need to position a bootstrap modal(dialog) relative to the opener

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I use a bootstrap modal for my settings dialog in an angularJS app. but it need to open relative to the opener but the default bootstrap behavior is that it opens in the center of the page.I'm looking for a way to open it up and keep it relative to the opener when scrolling.

Code:

Modal template

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title">I&#39m a modal!</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <ul>
            <a href="#">hello</a>
        </ul>
        Selected: <b>123</b>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <p>Done</p>
    </div>
</script>
```

HTML

```
   <span class="settings" ng-click="open(lg)"></span>
```

JS

```
$scope.open = function (size) {
    console.log($document.find('my_items_wdgt').find('settings'))
    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
        animation: true,
        appendTo: $document.find('hello123'),
        templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
        size: size,
        backdrop: true,
        windowClass: "myItemsModal",
        resolve: {
            brands: function () {
                return $rootScope.usersBrands;
            }
        }
    });
};
```

[image]

Comment: Post your code or better demo. And looks like your image is not relevant at all.

Comment: I edited my post to include the code!

Comment: And the photo shows the modal opened next to the opener.

Comment: Maybe should you used [popover](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers-examples) instead of modal....

Comment: Thought about it but it needs to close on click away?

Comment: I said image is not relevant, because it's a popover not a modal on it. So yes, you should use popover. You can also close it on "click away" too.

Comment: Thanks but I actually wanted to use a modal to be able to have scope and more functionality within. but I think a popover would work Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem today. This is the solution I found and it's working in my project.

```
        var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            animation: true,
            backdrop: true,
            backdropClass: "modal-backdrop-custom",
            template:"<h1>Hello World!</h1>" 
        }).rendered.then(function (modal) {
            var element = document.getElementById("elementIdHere"),
                rect = element.getBoundingClientRect(),
                modal = document.querySelector('.modal-dialog');

            modal.style.margin = 0;
            modal.style.left = rect.left + 'px';
            modal.style.top = rect.top + 'px';



        });
```

Basically you get the position of the relative component and then set the same value to the top and left properties of the modal.

Hope this helps you!

Comment: My modal was jumping with this configuration so what I did was just set the modal dialogs `visibility` to `hidden` (css) and after setting the last `top` set it back to `visible` so that the jump isn't visible.

Answer (score 1):

It will get target attribute of opener or relative element give in bootstrap button.

```
$(".position-modal").click(function(e) {
        var getid = $(this).attr("data-bs-target");
        console.log(getid)
        var thisleft = $(this).offset().left;
        var thistop = $(this).offset().top;
        var thiswidth = $(this).width();
        var thisheight = $(this).height();
        var idwidth = $(getid).width();
        var idheight = $(getid).height();
        console.log(thisleft)
        $(getid + " .modal-content").css({left: thisleft - Number(idwidth/2) + Number(thiswidth/2), top: thistop - Number(idheight/2) + Number(thisheight), opacity:0.2});
    });
```

Comment: I'm guessing this is working on an older BS version.  I had to adjust data-bs-target to  $(this).attr("data-target"); to get to work.